# How to avoid duplication of values while adding multiple values to a textbox dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add multiple values to a hidden field. 
It's working fine, but I want the values which are getting added in the hidden field to be unique and not to get added if a value is entered more than once.

*interestedin* is the name of the selectbox where the values are selected and *interest* is the id of the hiddenfield where the values are getting added as comma separated values while selecting options in the selectbox.

if a same option is selected twice, it's getting added in the hidden field twice. I don't want any values to get added in the hidden fields though its selected twice.

the function clicker is called while selecting the values in the select box(name="interestedin") and the values will be added in the hidden field (id="interest")

```
function clicker(){
            var itemsobj=document.getElementsByName("interestedin[]");
            str='';
            //alert(itemsobj[0].value);
            //alert('test');
            count=0;
            var arr = new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<itemsobj.length;i++)
        {
            count += 1;
            str +=itemsobj[i].value+',';
            //alert(str);
            arr[i] = itemsobj[i].value; 
                }
            var length=str.length;
            var strr=str.substring(0,length-1);
            document.getElementById('interest').value = strr;
            //alert(strr);


            setProductPrice(arr,count);
        }
```

Comment: please create a fiddle on http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Is it posible to add few js files in fiddle? cuz the selectbox is facebook style autocomplete..

Comment: Yes. You can add external JS and CSS in the JS and CSS field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiya sup man hope this helps as I just resolved for some **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Yvnfx/
 **or** without alert http://jsfiddle.net/Yvnfx/1/

**For case - if you deleted the selected autocomplete** http://jsfiddle.net/wbQZU/4/

[Autocomplete (like facebook) has give up a duplicate value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383014/autocomplete-like-facebook-has-give-up-a-duplicate-value/)

Idea is to created `NewArray = AvailableTagsArray - UsedItemArray`

This will help and hope demo makes it more clear,! B-)

**Jquery code to avoid duplicate array**

```
**var usedItems = []**
:
:// then
source: function(request, response) {

      //build new array with = AvailableTagsArray - UsedItemArray
             var newNonDuplicatetag = $.grep(availableTags, function(el){return $.inArray(el, usedItems) == -1});

            // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
            response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            newNonDuplicatetag, extractLast(request.term)));
        },
```

**Full Jquery from my demo**

```
$(function() {
    var usedItems = [];

    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
        ];

    function split(val) {
        return val.split(/,\s*/);
    }

    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }


    $("#tags")
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {
             var newNonDuplicatetag = $.grep(availableTags, function(el){return $.inArray(el, usedItems) == -1}); 
            // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
            response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            newNonDuplicatetag, extractLast(request.term)));
        },
        focus: function() {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            usedItems.push(ui.item.value);
            alert(usedItems[1]);
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push("");
            this.value = terms.join(", ");
            return false;
        }
    });
});


​
```